# Looping Picasso to load url image

Tags: java, android, imageview, picasso

I want to display images from URL with regular interval using Picasso. It display single image very fine but when I loop it either it create error or does not show. I'm pasting my code here that is not displaying any image to image view

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {

    Integer i=1;
    String adurl = "http://mywebsite.com/img";
    String nADURL;
    private Context mContext;
    private int index = 0;
    private final int interval = 3000;
    private final int DURATION = 1500;
    ImageView iv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

        //Initializing the ImageView
       iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivAdd);

        showAd9 sh = new showAd9();    
        sh.execute("3000");
    }

  public  class showAd9 extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                nADURL = adurl.toString() + String.valueOf(i) + ".png";
                try {
                    int time = Integer.parseInt(params[0]);
                    while(i<=4) {
                        Picasso.with(main.this).load(nADURL).skipMemoryCache().error(R.drawable.wrong).into(iv);
                        i++;
                        Thread.sleep(time);
                    }

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {  
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should not be call Picasso load into from a background thread. You do not need to take care of threading, Picasso does it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is not straight-forward - I think it's better to do this stuff with help of `Handler`. And the point is that you do the loading with Picasso from background thread. `Picasso` handles this for you, just schedule your interval with `Handler.postDelayed()` - this should solve your problem.